# How to delete lines matching a specific pattern with Notepad++

Tags: regex, find-and-replace

I need to leave the lines that have both username and password like this:

```
username:password
```

I need to delete lines not having a correlated username like this:

```
:password
```

**Full example file containing:**

```
username:password
:password0
username:password1
username:password2
:password
username:password4
:password2
username2:password5
```

**Needed result:**

```
username:password
username:password1
username:password2
username:password4
username2:password5
```

Comment: For the final part to delete empty lines: Find `\n\n`, replace with `` (nothing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `(\s:.)([^\s]+)` Regular expression and the `Replace with` option leaving it blank to get the expected results.

Once you open your document with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) just press <kbd>**`Ctrl`**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**`H`**</kbd> and go to the <kbd>**`Replace`**</kbd> tab. From there just put the `(\s:.)([^\s]+)` in the `Find what:` field and leave the `Replace with` empty, be sure the `Regular expression` option is checked, and then press <kbd>**`Replace All`**</kbd> option.

> ### Essentially this will:
>
> Find matching strings that start with a white space and then followed by a colon `:` which is followed by any characters until the
>   next white space to this matches the `:password` where there is a
>   trailing and leading white space between the strings.

### Screen Shot

[image]

### Before

```
username:password :password0 username:password1 username:password2 :password username:password4 :password2 username2:password5
```

or

```
username:password
:password0
username:password1
username:password2
:password
username:password4
:password2
username2:password5
```

### After

```
username:password username:password1 username:password2 username:password4 username2:password5
```

or

```
username:password

username:password1
username:password2

username:password4

username2:password5
```

If the above is no good in this format, go to `Edit` and select the `EOL Conversion` option and then select the `UNIX/OSX Format` and then go back to the same option and then select the `Windows Format` and that'll get all the carriage return and line feeds back to Windows format `CR/LF`.

Once that is complete you can go up to `Edit` and select the `Line Operations` and then select the `Remove Empty Lines` option and you'll have the exact format you need removing empty the lines.

```
username:password
username:password1
username:password2
username:password4
username2:password5
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Quick-Start: Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^:.+\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^         # beginning of line
  :       # semicolon
  .+      # 1 or more any character but newline
  \R?     # any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n), optional (in order to delete the last line)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
username:password
username:password1
username:password2
username:password4
username2:password5
```